# Automate Oracle 11g Database backupsteps

Tags: oracle11g, command-line-arguments

I have to automate the Oracle 11g datbase backup . I am using followng synatx running through windows command prompt.

```
rman.exe  target sys/Logility_123@newdb  @'C:\cmdfile.txt'
```

and my text file has following commands

```
RUN
{
 Shutdown immediate;
 Startup mount;
 Backup Database;
 ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

}
```

I am getting the following error as in below snapshot.
[image]

Please advise how to troubleshoot this problem.